# DRF, why my root api urls are got mixed (combined)?

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, serialization, django-rest-framework

These are my code snippets:

```
# serializers.py
from rest_framework import serializers
from .models import User


class UserSerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = '__all__'


class UserActivitySerializer(serializers.HyperlinkedModelSerializer):
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = (
            'id',
            'email',
            'last_login',
            'last_requested_at',
        )
```

```
# urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet)
router.register(r'user-activity', UserActivityViewSet)

urlpatterns = [
    path('', include(router.urls)),
]
```

This leads to combined Root API urls, like so:
[image]

However this is not the expected behavior. I wanted 2 separate urls. First with all users (for example, localhost:8000/users with all users and localhost:8000/users/ for specific user). And second with **user activity** API. with those 4 fields. I don't have clue why my urls got combined when I added `router.register(r'user-activity', UserActivityViewSet)` to my **urls.py**. Please help with broad explanation, if possible. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to specify the `basename` to the routes like this:

```py
# urls.py
router = routers.DefaultRouter()
router.register(r'users', UserViewSet, basename="users")
router.register(r'user-activity', UserActivityViewSet, basename="user-activity")

urlpatterns = [
    path("", include(router.urls)),
]
```

PS.: Some DRF versions call that as `base_name`

Comment: This totally worked for me! Thanks a lot. I have a small question though, now with your configs, my ```localhost:8000/users/``` raises an error **ImproperlyConfigured at /users/**, but when I changed the first **basename** from ```users``` to ```user``` it worked fine. I know the answer should be obvious, but anyways could you please explain please. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Probably the basename `"users"` already exists on DRF routes. Do you can list all routes in the application with this command: `python manage.py show_urls`